# CURL/Mac: error while downloading. Protocol "https" not supported (error 1)

Tags: https, openssl, curl, homebrew, composer

I experience issues with both Composer and Wordpress (npm doesn't seem to be affected )
The error message from Composer is exactly `https://repo.packagist.org could not be fully loaded (curl error 1 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: Protocol "https" not supported or disabled in libcurl), package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date`

However, when I check my curl protocols settings `curl -V` I get that `https` is added to the Protocols list.
I've tried to install curl from homebrew, both regular curl and openssl-curl (`curl-openssl`). The curl-openssl seems no longer relevant but I tried it just to deplete all options.
I exported the `$PATH`.
I tried some while ago to install it from curl.haxx.se but either this issue started with that or very least it didn't resolve it.

I feel like I've tried everything from every forum, git discussion and blog posts that I could find but I haven't been able to solve it.

- curl version Mac OS X: `7.64.1`
- curl version Brew: `7.78.0`
- OS: macOS Big Sur `11.4`

Any help is really appreciated.